# What does "String => String" notation mean when putting it as the return value of a function in Scala Language?

Tags: scala, function, programming-languages

I have this doubt for example in the following function definition (specifically in the return type "String => String"):

```
def myFunction(line: String): String => String = {
    _.toLowerCase()
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Playing a little bit with the REPL made me finally understand this.

Comment: `myFunction()` returns a function that takes a `String` and returns a `String`.

Comment: So what would be the difference compared with just defining a function like: `def myFunction2(line: String): String = { line.toString }`

Comment: `myFunction()` takes a `String` as an argument and ignores it. It returns a function that takes its own `String` (supplied by the caller of the returned function) and returns a new (different) `String`. `myFunction2()` takes a `String` argument and uses it to return a new `String` of the same content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little time playing around in the Scala REPL demonstrates what's going on.

```
Welcome to Scala 2.12.7 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 10.0.2).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> def myFunction(line: String): String => String = {
     |     _.toLowerCase()
     | }
myFunction: (line: String)String => String

scala> myFunction("ABCD")
res0: String => String = $$Lambda$1148/1409513883@5a0e0886

scala> res0("WxYz")
res1: String = wxyz
```

Notice that the 1st passed argument, `"ABCD"`, doesn't do anything. It's the string that gets passed to the returned function, `res0`, that is transformed.

Answer (score 1):

That arrow in a type position is just a shorthand for the trait `Function1[+T1,-R]`, so `String => String` gets desugared into `Function1[String,String]`. It's called a [Function type](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#function-types).

Fun thing is that can use any type constructor that takes two type parameters as an [infix](http://gigiigig.github.io/tlp-step-by-step/infix-operator.html) operator, for example you could roll your own (admittedly rather useless) Tupler:

```
type Pair[T1,T2]=Tuple2[T1,T2]
val a: String Pair String = ("this","that")
```

The only thing making that arrow somewhat special is that it's got its own name in the language spec and its right-associativity (note: you can also define your right-associative operators, but their name havs to end in `:`).